# <input> doesn't inherit the font from <body>

Tags: css

I have input and label fields:

```
<label class="adm" for="UserName">User name</label>
<input class="adm" id="UserName" name="UserName" size="30" type="text" value="" />
```

and CSS:

```
body,html { font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; margin:0; padding:0; color: #111;}
label.adm  { font-size:0.9em; margin:0 0 3px 3px; display: block;}
input.adm  { font-size:0.9em; margin:0 0 3px 3px; }
```

When the code opens up in Firefox the fonts are not the same. Firebug shows that both "should" inherit and when I look at computed it shows the label uses Verdana. However the input shows it uses "MS Shell Dlg".

Can anyone explain what's happening and why it doesn't seem to obey the normal CSS rules?

Comment: it's very sad they dont. I guess the W3C had decided it would be better to leave them to be styled as the system's default rather than forcing their own broswer styling on them

Answer (score 151):

It does not inherit by default but you can set it to inherit with css

```
input, select, textarea, button{font-family:inherit;}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pEedc/1/

Comment: font property automatic inherit if it is not mentioned, see here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font

Comment: @diEcho, this is true for all elements besides form elements, which inherit from the current system styling so they maintain a feel that is familiar to the user (*by default*), but they are manually overridable.

Comment: Wrong or not, what Firebug was showing me was very confusing: font size 12, but computed it still became 13.3333. After setting font-size to inherit analogous to Gaby's answer my problem was solved :O

Comment: @Gaby It is always so good that the designers make all the thinking for us developers... ;)

Comment: Also if you put the `input` inside `label`, the `label` tag doesn't inherit default css

Comment: Add `option,` to this list? That controls the individual options in a drop-down selection.

Answer (score 16):

Form items (inputs/textarea/etc) don't inherit font information.  You'll need to set the font-family on those items.

Comment: @jhon wat ever u r saying may b true, is there any standard/valid document regarding this??

Comment: font elements also doesn't inherit color, background and so on. Actually, font elements are the most unreliable thing in the whole html/css! You cannot specify a width for an input box and guarantee will be the same across all browsers!

Comment: I mean form elements. Still sleepy :)

Comment: @diEcho - Honestly, I did a search through the specs, and don't see it called out anywhere.  Looking over at 'Related', and SO is giving me a duplicate question link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874813/ (which gives my answer, although also with no spec links).  The default stylesheet in Chrome lists the font as "-webkit-small-control;", which means it is already overriding body, therefore is more specific than anything set on body.  The same goes for TD elements, if I'm not mistaken.    So I don't know what to say other than "that's just how it is." : )

Answer (score 5):

Three years later, I'm finding it strange `<input>` elements of types `reset`, `submit`, and `button` don't inherit `font-family` in Chrome or Safari. I discovered they would not receive padding either.

But when I mess with certain properties, like `background`, `border`, or this strange `appearance` property, then `font-family` and `padding` have effect, but the native look and feel of the button is lost, which is not a problem if you are completely restyling the buttons.

If you want a native looking button, with inherited `font-family`, use the `<button>` element instead of `<input>`.

See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jehoshua02/pen/ByWzor).

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem. What worked for me was adding the style directly to the input element in the html. I'm coding in React fyi.

`<input style={{fontFamily: "YOUR_FONT_CHOICE_HERE"}} />`

Answer (score -1):

This question is 10 years old, and some people coming to this recently may find that adding the right `<meta>` information at the top of the HTML page will fix similar issues experienced on mobile devices - try:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

MDN has a good guide to what the [viewport meta information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) does