# IE 8 - font-family display problem

Tags: css, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have an application that has an initial login page that 
has a user name and password input box.
This page works fine in IE 7, Safari , Firefox 4 & 5 but not
in IE 8 and 9. In IE 8/9 the user name and password display with
different size input boxes when you adjust the zoom percent. 
While doing some testing I noticed in IE 8/9 the Document Mode is in Quirks Mode.
So I tried setting the Document Mode in IE 9 to IE 9 Standards mode and
the page displays correctly. However in IE 8 it has no affect.
The only thing I have been able to get to work is to redefine 
the font-family in the style sheet for the input boxes. This works
for IE 7,8 and 9 and also Safari and Firefox.

I have also tried setting the DOCTYPE and meta tags but none of those
combinations seem to work in IE 8.

I included a test stylesheet and html below that reproduces
the problem.

Does anyone know why IE 8/9 would require this ? Is there another
way to handle this other than redefining the font-family ?

Thank you.

The stylesheet below works in IE 7, Safari and Firefox 4 & 5. In IE 8/9 it causes
the user name and password to display with different lengths unless I use the commented
out line:

stylesheet:

```
body                   { font-size: x-small; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, Swiss, SunSans-Regular;} 


form                    { font-size: 100%; }
input                   { font-size: 110%; }
/*input                   { font-size: 110%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, Swiss, SunSans-Regular; }*/
INPUT.TEXT              { font-size: 100%; }
select                  { font-size: 110%; }
textarea                { font-size: 110%; }
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>                 
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>                  
<table>                 
<tr><td>User&nbsp;Name: </td><td><input type=text name=username size=20 value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type=password name=pass size=20></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=submit value=Login></td></tr>
</table>                
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input length is based on your font-size. But many form element do not inherit your font-family. 
Test it with a funky font (Comic Sans MS) and a big font-size.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080413/why-doesnt-input-inherit-the-font-from-body) (except the first answer is wrong, input type do not inherit font-family).

You could set your input size in CSS (`width:200px`).

Little note : `INPUT.TEXT` points to no element. `.text` is a class.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I guess I still don't see why the font-family appears to be inherited in IE 7, Safari and Firefox but in IE 8/9 you need to specify the font-family for input.

Comment: It's not inherited unless you force it. Play with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz78R/) and you'll understand. I can't test for IE7, but I'm pretty sure it's a matter of rendering font differently. So yeah, for IE, you gotta redefine fonts attribute...