# Custom TextBox with input tag

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to make a custom TextBox (input) with a different font and transparent background, I found two posts on how to edit input font family and making backgrounds transparent.

[Is background-color:none valid CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739665/is-background-colornone-valid-css)
[Why doesn't <input> inherit the font from body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080413/why-doesnt-input-inherit-the-font-from-body)

But I'm trying

HTML:

```
<div id='test' class='menuInput' style='background-color:blue;' onClick='alert("Test");'><input type="text"></div>
```

CSS:

```
input,.menuInput{
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:35px;
    margin:0px auto;
    font-family:FixedSys;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    height:35px;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:400px;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

But its not working? the background color is still white and the font family hasn't changed either

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, but it still isn't working? I've tried

```
.menuInput input[type="text"]{
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:35px;
    margin:0px auto;
    font-family:FixedSys;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    height:35px;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:400px;
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

and its still not working?

I'm sure I have that font since I'm using it for something else!

Comment: Not reproducible with the code posted.

Comment: Testing with the HTML posted and either of the CSS pieces posted does *not* reproduce the problem described in the text. The poster’s own comment posted as an answer shows that the question does *not* contain sufficient information for actually reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.menuInput input[type=text]{
background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
color:#000;
font:12px bold "..";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/cEspM)

I removed the style that you mentioned in HTML and to check the transparency, set:

```
body{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Your font is not standard, in my opinion. Please provide the appropriate path to it.

Comment: I mean to use `@font-face`. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face OR http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Answer (score 0):

The background color for your input text is not transparent and it is in blue because you have given the " div" background color blue which overlap the input tag.

```
<div id='test' class='menuInput' style='background-color:blue;' onClick='alert("Test");'>  
     <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

Below is the code which is working and it is also accepting the font-family. There might be some font-family which might not be accepted. So check using different font-family. I have used " Courier and Arial " and it is accepting the first one.

```
HTML:
 <div id='test' class='menuInput'>
     <input type="text" />
 </div>

CSS:
input,.menuInput{
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:35px;
    margin:0px auto;
    font-family:Courier,Arial;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    height:35px;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:400px;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:black;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Holy Crap guys I'm sorry but the problem was that I literally only put the div in the .html and forgot about html head and body tags

**=_=**

Total Noob-Out there

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div id='test' class='menuInput'>
<input type="text" class="test1"/>
</div>
```

css

```
.menuInput{
    background-color:yellow;
}

input.test1{
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:35px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    height:35px;
    border:2px solid black;
    width:400px;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:red;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```