# Change font size inside input-fields with css

Tags: css, font-size, input-field

```css
html{
 font-size:62.5%;
}

body{
 font-family:arial;
 font-size:1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<p>LOREM IPSUM</p>
<p>LOREM IPSUM</p>

<input type = 'text' value = 'LOREM IPSUM'>
```

Why doesn’t `font-size:1.1rem` work inside input-fields?

How to get a global font-size for the entire page?

Comment: Your font size is equal in the input, but it sounds like you want it to be 1.1rem, is that right? Just add `input { font-size: 1.1rem; }`

Comment: @duhaime, why specifying `font-size` for `body` is not enough?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080413/why-doesnt-input-inherit-the-font-from-body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` fields are not effected by font variations you make for the `body` element. You have to style them separately.

To change that, use

```
input[type=text] {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because the `input` already have `font-size` defined by the user agent unlike `p` element so the `p` element **will inherit** the value defined by the `body` and `input` will use its own value unless you override it:

[image]

So the input element will have the computed value of `font-size` like follow:

[image]

As you can see, the font of the body is considered BUT it's overridden by the one already defined by default.