# Change size of text in text input tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a large input box for text but I can't change the font size?

`<input type="text">`

I would like to change the font size inside the text field but I can't seem to do it using CSS. Any help?

Comment: In case the purpose is to have the same size as in the outer text, see [Why <textarea> and <textfield> not taking font-family and font-size from body?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2874813/812102).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`<input style="font-size:25px;" type="text"/>`

The above code changes the font size to 25 pixels.

Comment: Adding inline styles is a bad practice. You should use the css method listed by @jacktheripper below.

Answer (score 25):

In your CSS stylesheet, try adding:

```
input[type="text"] {
    font-size:25px;
}
```

See this jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/jtLRM/)

Comment: Hey, Thanks I tried `font-size:25px;` on an id I had for the input but that didn't work. This works on the other hand so thanks.

Comment: plus one, for not using in-line styling in the html element

Comment: This worked for me. Needed to specify the type to get it to work, as opposed to just leaving it as global styling for any input.

Comment: @DraganMarjanovic If you're using an id, don't forget to use the # symbol in front of the id name.

Answer (score 2):

This works, too.

```
<input style="width:300px; height:55px; font-size:50px;" />
```

A CSS stylesheet looks better though, and can easily be used over multiple pages.

Comment: Adding inline styles is a bad practice. You should use the method listed by @jacktheripper above.

Comment: Inline styles is a fine practice for one-off styling, especially for small single-day or single-hour projects, such as for a proof-of-concept. The added overhead of separating out styling is make-work in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

I would say to set up the font size change in your CSS stylesheet file.

I'm pretty sure that you want all text at the same size for all your form fields. Adding inline styles in your HTML will add to many lines at the end... plus you would need to add it to the other types of form fields such as `<select>`.

HTML:

```
<div id="cForm">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" data-required="true">
        <option value="" selected="selected" >Choose Category...</option>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input, select {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript to change font size for an input control is:

```
input.style.fontSize = "16px";
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the font size of the `<input />` tag in HTML, use this:

```
<input style="font-size:20px" type="text" value="" />
```

It will create a text input box and the text inside the text box will be 20 pixels.

Comment: Editor note: Please fix your answer, format and data are missing. Failing to do this makes this answer bound to be deleted by the SO editors.

Comment: Adding inline styles is a bad practice. You should use the method listed by @jacktheripper above.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code into

```
<input class="my-style" type="text" />
```

CSS:

```
.my-style {
  font-size:25px;
}
```