# Change R Shiny widget input text size

Tags: r, shiny

So I have numInputs, and I want to change the text size of the number that actually appears inside the text box.

How would I achieve that?

Comment: You can use CSS. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363674/change-size-of-text-in-text-input-tag for example in HTML (you can use `tags$style` in Shiny to include CSS)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way, as @warmoverflow says, is using CSS. Below are two examples of adding some CSS to a widget, the first one will be only applied to the element with the specified id and the second will be for all the elements of type number. I'm assuming that it is `numericInput` instead of numInputs, but it should works with any other input widget.

Option 1. Changes the CSS for a specific element

```
runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tags$style("#myNumericInput {font-size:50px;height:50px;}"),
    numericInput("myNumericInput", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
    numericInput("otherNumericInput", "Observations 2:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
  )),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  })
))
```

Option 2. Changes the CSS of all the elements of type `number`.

```
runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    tags$style("[type = 'number'] {font-size:50px;height:50px;}"),
    numericInput("myNumericInput", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
    numericInput("otherNumericInput", "Observations 2:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
  )),
  server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  })
))
```

Please note that in addition to changing the font size, I also changed the heigh, this is to make sure that the box will be big enough to show the number with a different size.

Also, you could consider using a separate .css file to put all your custom styles.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I just put

```
input[type="number"] {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

into my CSS header style tags and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just a general note that might be interesting to others visiting this post:

It turns out that the `tags$style('#inputId {}')` approach does NOT work if your inputId has a `.` in it.

- For example: the following *does not change* the text size of the input text:

  ```
  tags$style("#myNumeric.Input {font-size:8px;}"),
  numericInput("myNumeric.Input", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
  ```

  ...but the following works as expected:

  ```
  tags$style("#myNumericInput {font-size:8px;}"),
  numericInput("myNumericInput", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
  ```

  - Note: `_` works ok in an inputId name.

If you insist on keeping a `.` in your inputId name, try adding the style argument directly to your input function instead:

```
    numericInput("myNumeric.Input", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100,
                 style = "font-size:8px;")
```