# Why does my body CSS affect my input CSS only when I use an em font-size for the input?

Tags: css

I always thought that body font and input font were separate. For example, if I have this for my HTML:

```
<div>some test text</div>
<input type="text"/>
```

and then this for my CSS:

```
body {
  font:2em verdana;
}
```

then only the div font is large and the input text stays small. But if I add this CSS:

```
input {
  font-size:1em;
}
```

then the input font size takes on the body font size. why?

Comment: Did you try using a more specific selector?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2875030/731323

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why <textarea> and <textfield> not taking font-family and font-size from body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874813/why-textarea-and-textfield-not-taking-font-family-and-font-size-from-body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're right with your first sentence: input elements usually don't inherit font-sizes.

with using `em` this doesn't work anymore, because `1em` is, by definition, the font-size of an element - and if you set the font-size to `em`, it's based on the parent-elements font-size, because the element itself doesn't have an absolute font-size anymore.

so using `font-size: 1em` on inputs is basically kind of like using `font-size: inherit` for inputs and `px` for the body-setting.