# What is default font style of textarea in chrome? (text input vs textarea "size" of text)

Tags: css, fonts, textarea, default-value

What is default font style of textarea in chrome? What should to make it default look like?
Purpose of my question is that I wanna make the text make same in input as in textarea. In text input is maybe too "bold" :P 
The question should be: **What are default font properties applied on textarea? What would I wrote if I wanna look like as default?**

```
textarea {
font-???: ???;
etc.
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question directly,

The default font property of a `textarea` is `font-family: monospace`

While the default font property of a `input` is `font-family: Arial`.

All the default styling properties of an element (in Chrome) can be found by looking at the **computed** styling of the element in the Chrome developer tool. For all the properties, view this [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/CBFth/)

Comment: Thx and nice example :)

Comment: If I set the font-family to an unsupported font (e.g. "ArialMT"), then Times New Roman is set instead of monospace. Why?

Comment: This is not the case for both Safari and Chrome on macOS, and any browsers on iOS; Helvetica is used instead. I don't know **why** this is the case, though.

Comment: ^^^ for `textarea` (i.e. Helvetica instead of a monospace font)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2875114/2498874), you can force textarea to inherit the font style, to make it look like default:

```
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```