# How to make font size in textarea same as input field in CSS?

Tags: html, css, font-size

The font size in the textarea in https://jsfiddle.net/Ljxwre2y/ is smaller than in the input field, how can I make them both the same size?

```
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 30px;
}

input,textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

Comment: It seems that input and textarea using different font family. That mean that the font size itself wont help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013784/what-is-default-font-style-of-textarea-in-chrome-text-input-vs-textarea-size

Answer (score 1):

add font-size in both input, textarea

```
input,textarea{
font-size: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I usually do, always works for me.

in your body tag, specify **font-family**
and others... like **font-size**.

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', monospace;
}
```

then, inherit...

```
textarea,
input,
select {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    color: #19272D; /*your input color*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly set them in CSS to prevent the browser from using the browser defaults. Like this:

```
input, textarea {font-size: 14px;}
```

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/678g930h/)

```
input, textarea {font-size: 14px; font-family: sans-serif;}
```

Use the above code to make the fonts exactly the same (so not only the size). See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgm07t2x/)

Comment: Tried that in the jsfiddle, it doesn't work. And even so I want them to get the values that have been set for the whole document rather than having to duplicate the font-size value for these elements which have already been defined on `body`.

Comment: It works (see jsfiddle). Please change your question if you have a different question (or ask a new one).

Comment: I'm using chrome on linux and the input text is still larger than the textarea text for me.

Comment: Font-size is the same... font-family is not. If you explicitly set the font-family the same too (not inherit them), the fonts will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Monsterrat";
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Both `input` and `textarea` doesn't inherit font family. So you need to set `font-family` property to either your font name or `inherit` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the '*' selector to set fonts, size and Family, then it will apply to `all` elements on the page, like this:

```
* 
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-Family: Arial;
}
```

Add this as the first entry in your css.