# Why does changing the font family change the font size?

Tags: html, css, font-size, font-family

I have a `<textarea>` inside the `<body>`. I have applied the following CSS rules:

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
textarea {
    font-family: monospace;
    /* font-family: "Courier New", monospace; */
}
```

Here's what it looks like in Firefox 31.0:

[image: Imgur]

You can see the result in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JGh9X/2/). By inspecting the `<textarea>` with Firebug we can see it does not inherit the `<body>`'s `font-size`, but sets it instead to `13px`. (`0.8em`?)

[image: Imgur]

However, if I uncomment the second `font-family` declaration, [strange things happen](http://jsfiddle.net/JGh9X/3/).

[image: Imgur]

Now the `<textarea>` seems to inherit `<body>`'s `font-size`, even though I didn't change it manually.

Finally, in both cases, Firebug shows that the `font-size: 16px` of `<body>` is overridden, even though I didn't find any browser stylesheets there that override it.

[image: Imgur]

This does not seem to occur in Internet Explorer 11 or Chrome 34.

The problem is easily fixed by setting `font-size: 0.8em` to all `<textarea>`s, but the cause bothers me a bit.

What may be the cause of this? A bug in Firefox, possibly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why <textarea> and <textfield> not taking font-family and font-size from body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874813/why-textarea-and-textfield-not-taking-font-family-and-font-size-from-body)

Comment: @Paulie_D Don't think so; I know the elements don't inherit said properties automatically.

Comment: @Pietu1998 You should be able to use the inspector to see where the font is being changed. It should point to the `textarea` due to the same issue Paulie_D linked

Comment: @ZachSaucier [Here](http://pastebin.com/5UkU7t8R) are all the rules that apply to the working `<textarea>`, and [here](http://pastebin.com/N4gj4fWL) are all that apply for the non-working one. The only difference is the `font-family` rule, and the only `font-size` applies to `<body>` (shown overlined for both cases).