# Unable to edit <textarea> font size in bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using some source code for an AJAX chat application and I cleaned it up and used it on a page I built in bootstrap. However, I'd like to change the font size of the textarea where the messages are posted.

HTML:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="chatwindow" style="min-height: 100%; font-size:30px;" cols="95" wrap="hard" readonly></textarea><br />
```

The AJAX post javascript if that helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var nick_maxlength=10;
    var http_request=false;
    var http_request2=false;
    var intUpdate;

    /* http_request for writing */
    function ajax_request(url){http_request=false;if(window.XMLHttpRequest){http_request=new XMLHttpRequest();if(http_request.overrideMimeType){http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');}}else if(window.ActiveXObject){try{http_request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}catch(e){try{http_request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}catch(e){}}}
    if(!http_request){alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');return false;}
    http_request.onreadystatechange=alertContents;http_request.open('GET',url,true);http_request.send(null);}
    function alertContents(){if(http_request.readyState==4){if(http_request.status==200){rec_response(http_request.responseText);}else{}}}

    /* http_request for reading */
    function ajax_request2(url){http_request2=false;if(window.XMLHttpRequest){http_request2=new XMLHttpRequest();if(http_request2.overrideMimeType){http_request2.overrideMimeType('text/xml');}}else if(window.ActiveXObject){try{http_request2=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}catch(e){try{http_request2=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}catch(e){}}}
    if(!http_request2){alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');return false;}
    http_request2.onreadystatechange=alertContents2;http_request2.open('GET',url,true);http_request2.send(null);}
    function alertContents2(){if(http_request2.readyState==4){if(http_request2.status==200){rec_chatcontent(http_request2.responseText);}else{}}}

    /* chat stuff */
    chatmsg.focus()
    var show_newmsg_on_bottom=1;     /* set to 0 to let new msg´s appear on top */
    var waittime=3000;        /* time between chat refreshes (ms) */

    intUpdate=window.setTimeout("read_cont();", waittime);
    chatwindow.value = "loading...";

    function read_cont()         { zeit = new Date(); ms = (zeit.getHours() * 24 * 60 * 1000) + (zeit.getMinutes() * 60 * 1000) + (zeit.getSeconds() * 1000) + zeit.getMilliseconds(); ajax_request2("chat.txt?x=" + ms); }
    function display_msg(msg1)     { chatwindow.value = msg1.trim(); }
    function keyup(arg1)         { if (arg1 == 13) submit_msg(); }
    function submit_msg()         { clearTimeout(intUpdate); if (chatnick.value == "") { check = prompt("please enter username:"); if (check === null) return 0; if (check == "") check="..."; chatnick.value=check; } if (chatnick.value.length > nick_maxlength) chatnick.value=chatnick.value.substring(0,nick_maxlength); spaces=""; for(i=0;i<(nick_maxlength-chatnick.value.length);i++) spaces+=" "; v=chatwindow.value.substring(chatwindow.value.indexOf("\n")) + "\n" + chatnick.value + spaces + "| " + chatmsg.value; if (chatmsg.value != "") chatwindow.value=v.substring(1); write_msg(chatmsg.value,chatnick.value); chatmsg.value=""; intUpdate=window.setTimeout("read_cont();", waittime);}
    function write_msg(msg1,nick1)     { ajax_request("w.php?m=" + escape(msg1) + "&n=" + escape(nick1)); }
    function rec_response(str1)     { }

    function rec_chatcontent(cont1) {
        if (cont1 != "") {
            out1 = unescape(cont1);
            if (show_newmsg_on_bottom == 0) { out1 = ""; while (cont1.indexOf("\n") > -1) { out1 = cont1.substr(0, cont1.indexOf("\n")) + "\n" + out1; cont1 = cont1.substr(cont1.indexOf("\n") + 1); out1 = unescape(out1); } }
            if (chatwindow.value != out1) { display_msg(out1); }
            intUpdate=window.setTimeout("read_cont()", waittime);
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see I've tried assigning it the CSS font-style attribute in a style tag but that didn't work. Beforehand I simply tried styling it in my style.css file, like `textarea {font-size: 30px;}`

I'm also using a bootstrap theme that replaces the header tags with something else so I won't have any luck changing the size with the  to  tags.

Note that changing the font size in the CSS stylesheet will change it everywhere but the textarea it looks like. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117290/how-to-change-font-size-in-a-textbox-in-html

Comment: The inline style takes precedence over css, unless: 1- The style on css has the `!Important` directive or 2 - Javascript creates a completely different DOM. Try using this: `style="min-height: 100%; font-size:30px !important;"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain controls are not defaulted to inherit font settings. You can override this by place this in your CSS:

```
textarea {
   font-size: 30px!important;
}
```